# Joomla timezone different from MySQL timezone

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, xampp

In Joomla I've correctly set my timezone to Eastern Time.  I'm running my server locally with xampp.  I can see that in my php.ini that my date.timezone is set to America/New_York, also Eastern Time.  However, somehow, whenever anything is modified in Joomla, the time that appears in the database for modified is 5 hours ahead.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Joomla in depth, but this looks like it's [by design](http://help.joomla.org/content/view/51/153/1/2/):

> Time Offset: Identifies the time zone in which the web site is to operate. The time offset is set in hours +/- between the web site location and UTC (Universal Time Coordinated - formerly referred to as GMT (Greenwich Mean Time)). Select the time zone from the drop down list.

Joomla seems to store UTC dates internally, and to calculate the difference when outputting data. So unless there are wrong dates visible in the *front-end*, I think this is fine.

Comment: It's not fine because it results in incorrect behavior.  If my records in the database all have the incorrect time, I can't do things based on the current time.  For example, I'm using the AutoArchive plugin which automatically looks for expired articles and moves them to the trash.  But the joomla expiration dates are 5 hours behind what's in the database

Comment: @JPC I see. But if I'm correct, they don't have the *incorrect* time, they have GMT/UTC time. You would have to recalculate the current time as UTC, which is easy e.g. with [`Datetime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php): `$date = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('UTC'));` and work with that. However, there *seems* to be an "internal time zone" setting somewhere in Joomla - it's hard to tell from the web results. Maybe it's worth looking into the configuration. Remember to make a database backup before changing anything in there

Comment: There's an offset in the configuration but I think it's linked to the timezone in the global configuration so when you modify one it changes the other, other than that, can't find anything

Comment: It would still be incorrect time if a date in UTC gets stored in MySQL where the date setting is different than UTC

Answer (score 0):

Your MySQL timezone is probably off. Whenever your script calls MySQL date/time functions like NOW() it will use the MySQL time. You can see what the current timezones are set to by running this query `SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone;`.

[Read more about it here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html)